# Use javascript to target element in php include

Tags: javascript, php, html, php-include

What's the best way to use javascript to target html elements included in an external php file?

I am adding/removing a class from my header whenever the client scrolls more than 20px from the top.  The header is saved in header.php which is an included file in each page.  This only works on html elements in the main pages.  How do I target elements in the included files when sensing changes in distance from the main file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript works on the client. It sees only the final output from PHP and knows nothing about what mechanism PHP might have used to create it. Treat your header exactly as if it were part of the main document.

Comment: This steered me in the correct direction after a bit of supplementary research. Thank you. One point, Gryffindor!